# RAW file system formating

Tags: filesystems

I have flash drive with a `RAW` file system. I would like to format it (with a filesystem such as `NTFS`). Is this possible?

The flash drive I have is a 16GB Kingston USB. Because it has a `RAW` file system Windows can't access it (and I therefore can't format it or convert it to another filesystem). I tried various different recovery programs (even though I didn't want to recover it, just change the file system). These included `Disk Management`, and the DOS `format` command.

Comment: What version of `Microsoft Windows` are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7

Comment: Have you tried deleting the existing RAW volume and creating a new volume?

Comment: Windows can mark a disk or partition as Raw because of corruption, or just because it is a file system like EX? it does not understand.  It is possible that a chkdsk with the /F option would "fix" chkdsk can also destroy data for the file system it does not understand.

Comment: @joeqwerty It does not allow me to delete or create the volumes. could you guide me using other methods?

Comment: @Psycogeek The result is: The type of the file system is RAW.
CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives. :(

Answer (score 1):

Someone asked a similar question [HERE](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-to-format-a-raw-file-system-pen-drive-to-fat32/2666a777-13f2-42ec-ab73-a1dbfa11b802).
In the end, the community moderator there suggested using [THIS](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Hard-Disk-Utils/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool.shtml) standalone program. All you need to do is select the `Device` (in this case your flash drive), and make sure `Filesystem` is set to `NTFS`. After that, your flash drive should work normally.

Comment: I tried the program but it said: Failed to format the device.

Comment: Did you run the program as an administrator?

Comment: Yes but the error occurs again.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of formatting your USB is to use a different operating system, such as Ubuntu. [THIS](http://juasoft.blogspot.co.nz/2012/01/format-raw-usb-drive-in-ubuntu.html) article here explains what you need to do to format it.

For clarity, I rewrote the instructions with far more detail, so as to make them easier to follow.

## Instructions

[image]

1. Download Ubuntu from [HERE](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and follow the instructions [HERE](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to put it on a flash drive.
2. Reboot your computer with the Ubuntu flash drive plugged in. When your BIOS appears, find the option to boot your computer from the flash drive.
3. If done successfully, you will be greeted by a window asking you if you want to `Try Ubuntu` or `Install Ubuntu`. Click `Try Ubuntu`.
4. You should be greeted by the Ubuntu desktop. This should look similar to the one you can see above. It is now that you should plug in the flash drive you would like to format.
5. Open a terminal window by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
6. Type `sudo -i` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. Type `fdisk -l` into the terminal window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Take note of the flash drive location. As shown below, the location of mine is `/dev/sda`. 
   [image]
8. Type `fdisk /dev/sdb` into the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (replace `/dev/sda` with the location of your flash drive). Type <kbd>n</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> 5 times.
9. Type <kbd>w</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
10. Type `mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1` into the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (once again replacing `/dev/sda` with the location of your flash drive, and adding a one on the end of it). This step may take a while
11. Remove the flash drive you booted Ubuntu from, and reboot your computer.

If you followed the instructions above, Windows should now recognize your USB, and you should be able use it as you normally would.

Comment: Thank you, but fdisk don't have the permission on the device and says Permission Denied!

Comment: @user3435517 I edited the instructions (hopefully making it work).

Comment: Hi again. I did what you said and everything done as well. but when I try to use the device again in Windows, it says that device must must be formatted and the problem occurs again.

Comment: @user3435517 Does Windows allow you to format it?

Comment: No it doesn't. I tried to format everything with Low level formatting tools and the tried to make a new partition and everything went done. but windows can't read or format it.

Comment: Same problem here. It does not work for me to.

Comment: Hi, I had same problem and used "EaseUS Partition Master 10.0" and formatted the device successfully. Then I stored a file and removed USB thumb, connected again and the file was there. so I thought problem was fixed. when I tried to format thumb from windows GUI, the problem occurred again (like before formatting with EaseUS) so what do you think about it?